# python load TFS dll's

Tags: python, dll, tfs

I try to load the Microsoft.TeamFundation dlls to check out a file with the python script

```
import os
import sys
import clr

clr.AddReference("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client") 
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client") 
clr.AddReference('TfsCheckout')

from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client import *
from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client import *
```

The dll's lie direct on the same location how the phyton script
the error occures at line

from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client import *

"No module named 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl'; 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation' is not a package"

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A TFS server can be accessed via the team foundation client which is shipped with Visual Studio and Team Explorer. You can have a look at the [TFS signal tracker prerequisites](https://help.timecockpit.com/html/a4c60754-23c4-47a9-91c6-bf99652ccd7d.htm#Prerequisites) should you require additional information on DLLs, supported versions and download sources.

Check the following snippet:

```
 import clr

        clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll")
        clr.AddReference("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll")
        clr.AddReference("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll")

        from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client import *
```

Useful blog: https://www.timecockpit.com/blog/2013/05/31/TFS-Work-Items-as-Time-Cockpit-Tasks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem in that way:

I have added an assembly resolve in the TfsCheckout.dll what is a self written helper dll from me. In the Phyton script I only load the TfsCheckout and the dll itself loads the needed references. The assembly resolve from .net site is no problem...